# Question regarding IP forwarding and running services at the same time

Tags: raspbian

I was wondering, is it possible to have ip forwarding on my pi enabled(e.g. follow this to configure it --> http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/) and at the same time expect that it can also be used e.g. to serve dns queries(e.g. running dnsmasq) ?

Thanks in advance,
Vincent

Comment: Note that I only use the eth interface.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem using any Linux host (pi included) as both server and router.  As long as there's not some port 53 port forward, it'll serve on your pi's ip just fine.

You should probably understand, however, that routing usually makes sense only when more than one interface is involved.  This can be two Ethernet NICs, an Ethernet and a wireless, or some combination of those and a virtual interface like a VPN, VLAN, or similar (or really, any combination of any of these).  And forwarding is not the same as connection sharing (related, but different).  Plus the hosts intending to use your device as a router will need routing updated to use it (e.g. by using it as their default gateway or similar).

In short, there's way more to making routing *useful* than what's in the linked guide.  So be careful and have fun learning how all this works!